# Visual studio 2015 extension to install .pfx key pair sn.exe

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, key-pair, sn

i was using vscommands extension for vs 2013 to import .pfx key into project by simply right clicking on error and applying fix.

in vs 2015 i didnt find any extension to do that an i have to manully enter command

- sn -d keyname
- sn -i key.pfd keyname
  [Sn.exe (Strong Name Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(v=vs.110).aspx)

is there any extension which can help to enter the password command easier ?

Comment: Do you mean run the command line and execute the command (like: sn -d keyname  ) via visual studio extension?

Comment: Yes, that i dont need to write the command manually. just entering password

Answer (score 1):

> is there any extension which can help to enter the password command easier?

I would suggest that you can create a simple Menu Command to achieve it. here is a sample for your reference.

Please modify the StartNotepad method like this:

```
 private void StartNotepad(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"yoursnPath\SN.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "-d keyname";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
            psi.Arguments = " -i key.pfd keyname";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
 }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx